# How to start and stop a camera feed with OpenCV and pyqt5?

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, pyqt5

I need to make an app that displays a video feed from a camera and I want to be able to start and stop the feed whenever I want. Here's what I've got so far: I start a fresh kernel, and I run the script below, and everything works as intended. Now I close the app with the Windows Close button, run the script again, I'm able to start the feed, however, when I try to stop the feed, it shuts down the kernel. I have no clue as to why this is happening.

EDIT: I just found out that starting and stopping multiple times crashes the kernel as well.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import cv2

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(300,300)
        self.globalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.feedLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.feedLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.feedLabel.setStyleSheet("background-color:pink")
        
         
        self.start_btn=QPushButton("Start feed", self)
        self.cancel_btn = QPushButton("Cancel", self)
        self.saveImg_btn=QPushButton("Save image", self)
        
        self.select_camera=QComboBox(self)
        self.select_camera.addItems(["0","1"])
        
        buttons_widget=QWidget(self)
        buttons_layout=QHBoxLayout(buttons_widget)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.start_btn)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.cancel_btn)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.saveImg_btn)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.select_camera)
        
        self.globalLayout.addWidget(self.feedLabel)
        self.globalLayout.addWidget(buttons_widget)
        
        self.setLayout(self.globalLayout)
        
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start_feed)
        self.cancel_btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_feed)
        
        #create a thread

        self.thread = QThread()
        #create a worker
        self.worker = Worker()
        #move worker to thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        #run method
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        

        self.worker.imageUpdate.connect(self.set_new_img)
        
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker_done)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread_done)
        
    
    def start_feed(self):
        self.worker.camera=cv2.VideoCapture(int(self.select_camera.currentText()), cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        self.worker.running=True
        
        #Start the thread
        self.thread.start()
        
    def stop_feed(self):
        self.worker.running = False
        print("feed was asked to stop")
        
    def worker_done(self):
        print("worker finished")
        self.worker.camera.release()
        self.thread.quit()
        
    def thread_done(self):
        print("thread finished")
        
    def set_new_img(self,Image):
        print("it received the signal")
        print(Image)
        self.feedLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(Image))
     
        
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal() #signals to communicate with main
    imageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage) #should be class attributes
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera=None
        self.running=None
    
    def run(self):
        
        while self.running:
            ret, frame = self.camera.read()
            if ret:
                Image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                FlippedImage = cv2.flip(Image, 1)
                ConvertToQtFormat = QImage(FlippedImage.data, FlippedImage.shape[1], FlippedImage.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                Pic = ConvertToQtFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                print("it got the pic")
                self.imageUpdate.emit(Pic)
                
        print("\nfinished signal emited")   
        self.finished.emit()
        
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Root = MainWindow()
    Root.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "kernel"?

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe it, since I don't exactly know the technical terms, but here's what happens: the app freezes, it closes and I get "Restarting Kernel" in the console. I'm running this on Spyder. Does that help?

Comment: Try running the program from the terminal or prompt.

Comment: It doesn't even allow me to stop once from the cmd. It simply closes the window that way whenever I hit the "Stop" button

Comment: I cannot test your code as I don't have a camera connected right now. Does it crash silently or do you get anything before that?

Comment: It just stops working and crashes. There's nothing before

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import cv2


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.globalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.feedLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.feedLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.feedLabel.setStyleSheet("background-color:pink")

        self.start_btn = QPushButton("Start feed", self)
        self.cancel_btn = QPushButton("Cancel", self)
        self.saveImg_btn = QPushButton("Save image", self)

        self.select_camera = QComboBox(self)
        self.select_camera.addItems(["0", "1"])

        buttons_widget = QWidget(self)
        buttons_layout = QHBoxLayout(buttons_widget)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.start_btn)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.cancel_btn)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.saveImg_btn)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.select_camera)

        self.globalLayout.addWidget(self.feedLabel)
        self.globalLayout.enter code hereaddWidget(buttons_widget)

        self.setLayout(self.globalLayout)

        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start_feed)
        self.cancel_btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_feed)

        # create a thread

        self.thread = QThread()enter code here
        # create a worker
        self.worker = Worker()
        # move worker to thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # run method
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        self.worker.imageUpdate.connect(self.set_new_img)

        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker_done)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread_done)

    def start_feed(self):

        self.worker.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(int(self.select_camera.currentText()), cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        self.worker.running = True

        # Start the thread
        self.thread.start()

    def stop_feed(self):
        self.worker.camera.release()
        print("feed was asked to stop")

    def worker_done(self):
        print("worker finished")
        self.worker.camera.release()
        self.thread.quit()

    def thread_done(self):
        print("thread finished")

    def set_new_img(self, Image):
        print("it received the signal")
        print(Image)
        self.feedLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(Image))


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()  # signals to communicate with main
    imageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)  # should be class attributes

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = None
        self.running = None

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            ret, frame = self.camera.read()
            if ret:
                Image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                FlippedImage = cv2.flip(Image, 1)
                ConvertToQtFormat = QImage(FlippedImage.data, FlippedImage.shape[1], FlippedImage.shape[0],
                                           QImage.Format_RGB888)
                Pic = ConvertToQtFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                print("it got the pic")
                self.imageUpdate.emit(Pic)

        print("\nfinished signal emited")
        self.finished.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Root = MainWindow()
    Root.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())`enter code here`
```

Comment: You can use:        self.worker.camera.release() in stope_feed function

Comment: Please improve the question by [edit]ing and adding a description. Don't use comments for that. Read more about [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).